# Changing color of frame when radio button is used

Tags: java, jframe, radio-button

I am trying to change the background color when a radio buttion is used.  Right now I have the frame, and buttons(red,green, and blue) showing.  I set up a method to change the color when a button is selected, but the background does not change.  What am I doing wrong?  What's missing?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;



public class FontViewerFrame extends JFrame
{
  private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 300;
  private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 400;
  private JRadioButton redButton;
  private JRadioButton greenButton;
  private JRadioButton blueButton;
  private ActionListener listener;

  /**
   Constructs the frame.
   */
  public FontViewerFrame()
  { 

    // This listener is shared among all components
    class ChoiceListener implements ActionListener
    { 
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
      { 
        setColor();
      }
    }

    listener = new ChoiceListener();

    createControlPanel();

    setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
  }
  /**
   Creates the control panel to change the color.
   */
  public void createControlPanel()
  {

    JPanel styleGroupPanel = createRadioButtons();

    // Line up component panels

    JPanel controlPanel = new JPanel();
    controlPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));


    controlPanel.add(styleGroupPanel);

    // Add panels to content pane

    add(controlPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
  }

  /**
   Creates the radio buttons to select the color.
   @return the panel containing the radio buttons
   */
  public JPanel createRadioButtons()
  {
    redButton = new JRadioButton("Red");
    redButton.addActionListener(listener);

    greenButton = new JRadioButton("Green");
    greenButton.addActionListener(listener);

    blueButton = new JRadioButton("Blue");
    blueButton.addActionListener(listener);
    blueButton.setSelected(true);

    // Add radio buttons to button group

    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
    group.add(redButton);
    group.add(greenButton);
    group.add(blueButton);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.add(redButton);
    panel.add(greenButton);
    panel.add(blueButton);
    panel.setBorder(new TitledBorder(new EtchedBorder(), "Color"));

    return panel;
  }
  public void setColor()
  {
    if(redButton.isSelected())
    {
      setBackground(Color.RED);
    }
    if(greenButton.isSelected())
    {
      setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    }
    if(blueButton.isSelected())
    {
      setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long story short, your `controlPanel` is covering the `contentPane` (because the default layout manager is `BorderLayout`) which is covering the `JRootPane` which is covering the frame...

[image: Basic Frame Structure]

Try changing the background color of the `controlPane` instead

You should also remember, by default, `JPanel` is opaque

Comment: Are all of these layers necessary or can I get rid of them and just have the frame with the buttons?

Comment: Yes, they are very necessary and no, you should not get rid of them.  Even if you did, you'd still have the same problem...

Answer (score 2):

```
getContentPane().setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
```

set color to whatever you want then

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add the action listener to the radio button group not each individual radio button